# Is Solr term support required for versions of Solr prior to 8.2?

Tags: solr

Sitecore documentation on Solr set up has a [section](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/80/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/walkthrough_setting_up_solr#_Toc399318998) on `Enabling Solr term support`, which is required to `power dropdowns in the UI`.  Which versions of Sitecore require this? `Sitecore 8.2` only, or `Sitecore 8.0 and 8.1`?

Comment: Drop downs in the UI?

Comment: Pete, I'm not sure what this means, but it is taken verbatim from Sitecore's documentation.

Comment: Dan, I'll check out the current project on 8 2. We are using SOLR 6 and to be honest, I didn't catch this setting in the doc like this. I don't have it enabled and haven't had any issues, at least noticably with any UI. Good question though. I'm curious.

Comment: Cool. I need to add this to the SIM Solr installer. I'll compare the UI with Lucene and  Solr with this both off and on, and update the ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this old question, and I'm sharing this link for posterity: https://grantkillian.wordpress.com/2017/02/17/auto-suggest-with-solr-facets-in-sitecore/

Sitecore’s dependence of the Solr “terms” component has changed with Sitecore 8.1 update-1 (rev. 151207).  Sitecore now uses faceting with Solr instead of terms.

Comment: Scratch that, you already wrote it. :)

Comment: This configuration detail is addressed by the SIM Solr install option (still in QA).  I updated the Github issue with a link to your article. https://github.com/dsolovay/Sitecore-Instance-Manager/issues/38

Answer (score 3):

This applies for all versions(8, 8.1 and 8.2).
On the documentation page there is a dropdown for each sitecore version and you will see that the documentation reffers to the same thing on all versions :)

Comment: Good observation, Diego. Since Solr implementation changed somewhat with 8.2, I will leave this open for a bit longer to see if anyone has direct experience with this functionality.

Comment: It is very weird that it is said everywhere that there are changes in setting up Solr on 8.2 but if you compare the docs between 8.2, 8.1 and 8.0 I can't see any difference. Could it be that the doc versioning got messed up here somehow?

Comment: @Gatogordo: Possibly. Will do more digging and update the question.